# InvokeScript works but WebPage replies "invalid argumment"

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

my script function is already defined in current loaded document

I am using

```
WebBrowser.InvokeScript Method (String, Object[])
```

as specified in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to invoke a javascript method with the same arguments specified here in href.

```
<a style="cursor: auto ! important;" id="13185-SL-CK-0" href="javascript:jpBook($('#13185-SL-CK-0'),'13185','SDAH','DBG','24-10-2015','SL','CK',3,false);" tabindex="1">Book Now</a>
```

My Code is :

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("jpBook", new object[] { "$('#13185-SL-CK-0')", "'13185'","'SDAH'","'DBG'","'24-10-2015'","'SL'","'CK'","3","false" });
```

However this doesn't work and i get a message from WebPage in a MessageBox that the arguments supplied to it are invalid.

However as you can see i have supplied the correct arguments.I am using a WebBrowserControl and have modified registry values for app to ensure that it emulates IE11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you need to pass without the inner single quotes as the JavaScript function is expecting a string SDAH for example not the string 'SDAH'

I haven't used the exact same api but in my project I'm invoking the script on a WebView passing a string from a variable which is just a normal string without the single quotes, also looking the MSDN example it looks they are doing the same.

For example I'm using:

anchorId is just a simple string variable like "Test1234"

C# code:

```
sender.InvokeScript("gotoAnchor", new string[] { anchorId });
```

Javascript code

```
function gotoAnchor(anchor) {
    var myanchor = anchor;
    var target_top=jQuery('#' + myanchor).offset().top-45;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target_top }, 600);
}
```

If I were you I'd try first with a simple function with just one parameter to see if it works, eg pass a string and write some text on html element, and then try the number and boolean values, at the end I'd also pass the first one

$('#13185-SL-CK-0' only like this "13185-SL-CK-0"

and will modify the js function to find the element inside as it might be expecting jquery object right now as parameter

Hope my assumptions are correct and this works out for you